# Is this an efficient way to obfuscate code and is it performance friendly?

Tags: java, obfuscation, performance, deobfuscation

So I recently thought of a way that would make code de-obfuscation a lot more difficult. But I am not quite sure if this affects the performance of my code negatively: So my idea is to turn this code:

```
public class SpeedTest1 {

public static void main(String[] args){
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    String toEncode = "fhsdakjfhasdkfhdsajkhfkshfv ksahyfvkawksefhkfhskfhkjsfhsdkfhjfhskjhafjkhskjadfhksdfhkjsdhfksfhksdhfsdyfieyt893489ygfudhgiueryriohetyuieyiuweatiuewytiueaytuiwfytwuiediuvnhuighsiudghfjdkghfsdkjghdiugfdkghdkjghdfkghfdghdigyeuriyeibuityeuirtuireytiuerythgfdkgiuegduigkghfdjkghjgkdfhgjfdhgjfdghfdkjghfdjkghfdkjghfdjkgfdjkghfdkjghfdjkgfdkjghfdkjgheriytretyretrityreiutyeriuhslfjlflkfflksdjflkjflks";
    String str = Base64.encode(toEncode.getBytes());
    try {
        System.out.println(new String(Base64.decode(str), "UTF-8"));
    } catch (Base64DecodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time: " + (end - start));
}
}
```

Into this code:

```
public class SpeedTest2 {

public static void main(String[] args){
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println(y(x(z(a().getBytes()))));

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time: " + (end - start));
}

private static String y(byte[] b){
    try {
        return new String(b, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private static byte[] x(String s){
    try {
        return Base64.decode(s);
    } catch (Base64DecodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private static String z(byte[] b){
    return Base64.encode(b);
}

private static String a(){
    return "fhsdakjfhasdkfhdsajkhfkshfv ksahyfvkawksefhkfhskfhkjsfhsdkfhjfhskjhafjkhskjadfhksdfhkjsdhfksfhksdhfsdyfieyt893489ygfudhgiueryriohetyuieyiuweatiuewytiueaytuiwfytwuiediuvnhuighsiudghfjdkghfsdkjghdiugfdkghdkjghdfkghfdghdigyeuriyeibuityeuirtuireytiuerythgfdkgiuegduigkghfdjkghjgkdfhgjfdhgjfdghfdkjghfdjkghfdkjghfdjkgfdjkghfdkjghfdjkgfdkjghfdkjgheriytretyretrityreiutyeriuhslfjlflkfflksdjflkjflks";
}
}
```

Now the second piece is more difficult to figure out about what it does. But now I am worried about the performance of my programm so I added the check time lines to see if one of the two is faster that the other one. Now most of the time they both print 0 as the time but sometimes one of the two print someting like 15 but that's never the same method. I did find this answer [[java how expensive is a method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495030/java-how-expensive-is-a-method-call]) that states that Java itself optimizes the code at run time so that would mean that it doesn't matter wich of the two examples to use right? As they are both equal at the time of execution. So I now want to know is this a good way to obfuscate code or does it affect code-efficiency negatively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding obfuscation in general:**

1) Against what do you want to protect?

1.1) A Java beginner understanding your code: Your approach may be ok

1.2) A Java expert understanding your code: Your approach won't really work and may not even slow the expert down by more than factor 2

1.3) A competitor understanding your code: Your approach won't really work, the competitor may put considerable resources on the task

2) Do you have to maintain the code later on?

2.1) Yes: You need something which translates your original sources to the obfuscated variants (see below)

2.2) No: You may be ok with it, however, if you need to fix a bug later on, you might not understand what you have created some time ago (it happens to experts regularly even with documented code...)

**Obfuscation tools:**

Having said that, you may want to look at [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net) ( http://proguard.sourceforge.net ). It is a Java obfuscator and it even improves performance on low resources platforms (mostly by shortening class and package names and reducing the size of the class files to push around).

There are encrypting class loaders. It raises the difficulty for your opponent, but you won't be safe - see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257027/how-can-you-protect-encrypt-your-java-classes).

**Regarding performance:**

You have to run performance tests with and without your change. And you need to do that on the platform on which the software shall run eventually. Some code is certainly slower and some certainly faster - however, eventually you need to test it.